# Modify Xamarin.Forms page from Xamarin.iOS file

Tags: firebase, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a Xamarin.Forms app that uses Firebase Authentication. In order to make Firebase work, I have to create two different platform-specific files (iOS and Android) to process the Authentication tasks (like CreateNewUser and Login). I have a Xamarin.Forms page called "Payment Page" that asks a user to enter their e-mail and password, and submitting this page triggers the DependencyService to create the user account. On the Payment Page, I also have a small window that will appear if something goes wrong with the account creation process (specifically in this case, if a duplicate e-mail already exists in the Auth database).

My question is, if one of the Dependency files for iOS or Android catches a 'ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE', how can I set the error dialog on the Payment Page to show (in other words, set its 'isVisible' property to 'true'). I've tried a number of things but so far cannot seem to reference elements in the PaymentPage (a Xamarin.Forms page) from the Xamarin.iOS Authentication page.

My Dependency code is as follows:

```
public void CreateNewUser(string email, string password, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection userData) 
{ 
    Auth.DefaultInstance.CreateUser(email, password, HandleAuthDataResultHandler); 
}

async void HandleAuthDataResultHandler(AuthDataResult authResult, Foundation.NSError error) 
{ 
     if(error.UserInfo["error_name"].ToString() == "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE") 
    { 
       //What goes here to modify the Xamarin.Forms page?? 
   }
 else { }
}
```

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing your service but probably the way to go would be that that service returns some kind of result where your viewmodel can reflect that situation.  That way you can keep responsibilities decoupled. Your service says how the user creation went and your viewmodel reflects that on the view.

Comment: If it helps, here's my CreateNewUser method in my iOS dependency:public void CreateNewUser(string email, string password, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection userData)
        {

            Auth.DefaultInstance.CreateUser(email, password, HandleAuthDataResultHandler); }

async void HandleAuthDataResultHandler(AuthDataResult authResult, Foundation.NSError error)
        {  if(error.UserInfo["error_name"].ToString() == "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE")
            {
              //What goes here??
            }
            else
            {

            }}

Comment: Oh now your questions makes way more sense. MessagingCenter might be a good way to go https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MessagingCenter might be a good way to go https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

You can suscribe your viewmodel and post a message from the handler with the result.

Comment: What would be the syntax? I've posted the following code in my Payment Page and it gives me an error 

MessagingCenter.Subscribe < DependencyService.Get<IFirebaseAuthenticator>() >

Comment: DependencyService.Get<IFirebaseAuthenticator>()  will return an instance not a type, although I never tried it using an interface my guess is MessagingCenter.Subscribe <IFirebaseAuthenticator> should work

Answer (score 1):

in your XAML code behind

```
try {
  // call your dependency service
} catch (Exception ex)
{
  // update the UI
}
```

then in your DependencyService method, it should throw an exception when an error condition occurs